# How to recover HDFS journal node?

Tags: hdfs

I have configured 3 journalnodes, let's say JN1, JN2, JN3. Each of them saves the edit log under /tmp/hadoop/journalnode/mycluster...

Based on which, I started my namenode, secondary namenode and bunch of datanode. The system runs well until one day **JN2** and **JN3** are dead. Furthermore, the disks are corrupted.

Then I purchased the new disks and restarted JN2 and JN3. The bad thing is it didn't work anymore.

It keeps complaining

```
org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.qjournal.protocol.JournalNotFormattedException: Journal Storage Directory /tmp/hadoop/dfs/journalnode/mycluster not formatted
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.qjournal.server.Journal.checkFormatted(Journal.java:457)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.qjournal.server.Journal.getEditLogManifest(Journal.java:640)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.qjournal.server.JournalNodeRpcServer.getEditLogManifest(JournalNodeRpcServer.java:185)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.qjournal.protocolPB.QJournalProtocolServerSideTranslatorPB.getEditLogManifest(QJournalProtocolServerSideTranslatorPB.java:224)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.qjournal.protocol.QJournalProtocolProtos$QJournalProtocolService$2.callBlockingMethod(QJournalProtocolProtos.java:25431)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Server$ProtoBufRpcInvoker.call(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:585)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Server.call(RPC.java:928)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:2013)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:2009)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1614)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler.run(Server.java:2007)
```

**Is there anyway to recover JN2 and JN3 from the only living JN1?**

Really appreciate all the possible solutions!

Thanks,
Miles

Answer (score 3):

I was able to fix the issues by creating missing directory on the Journal host where namenode will write the its' edit files.

Make sure the VERSION file is created, otherwise you will get `org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.qjournal.protocol.JournalNotFormattedException.`

or copy version file in directory

Comment: what is the location of VERSION file?

Comment: Location was /tmp

Answer (score 0):

The issue has gone after I duplicated the only existing /tmp/hadoop/journalnode/mycluster to JN2 and JN3.